# Access to Actual Class Variable from SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

As per spring's Event handling mechanism, we can use SpEL to select a specific handler under some circumstances. Taken from the spring doc.

```
public class EventXHandler {
    private String handlerClassName;
    @EventListener(condition = "#event.name == handlerClassName")
    public void processBlockedListEvent(BlockedListEvent event) {
        // notify appropriate parties via notificationAddress...
    }
}
```

My question is; if I can access to the handler class' property in the spel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; you cannot do that.

If you know the bean name and add a `public` getter for the property, you can use

`#event.name == @beanName.handlerClassName`.

Comment: Thx, my aim is to base on an abstract class and generate all handlers extending it.

Comment: One simple solution would be to put an if test in the listener `if (!event.getName().equals(this.handlerClassName) { return; } else {...}`. Perhaps not as elegant, but effective.

Comment: Well, spring already supports it. It calls your special handler with respect to your handler method's parameter type.